# aiohttp and gunicorn: logger doesn't work

Tags: gunicorn, aiohttp

I'm trying to debug my aiopg connection settings in production environment using aiohttp logger and gunicorn.

I'm trying to log my database credentials:

`models.py`:

```
async def init_pg(app):
    logger = logging.getLogger('aiohttp.access')
    logger.error("POSTGRES_USER = %s" % app['settings'].POSTGRES_USER)
    logger.error("POSTGRES_DATABASE = %s" % app['settings'].POSTGRES_DATABASE)
    logger.error("POSTGRES_HOST = %s" % app['settings'].POSTGRES_HOST)
    logger.error("POSTGRES_PASSWORD = %s" % app['settings'].POSTGRES_PASSWORD)

    app['engine'] = await create_engine(
        user=app['settings'].POSTGRES_USER,
        database=app['settings'].POSTGRES_DATABASE,
        host=app['settings'].POSTGRES_HOST,
        password=app['settings'].POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    )
```

This doesn't add any output to `/var/log/gunicorn/error_log`, although it is expected to.

Here is how I start gunicorn:

```
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn producer.main:app --daemon --bind 0.0.0.0:8002 --worker-class aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker --access-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/access_log --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/error_log --env ENVIRONMENT=PRODUCTION --timeout 120
```

Here is how I create aiohttp app:

`main.py`:

```
import logging

import aiohttp_jinja2
import jinja2
from aiojobs.aiohttp import setup as setup_aiojobs
from aiohttp_swagger import setup_swagger
from aiohttp import web, web_middlewares

from . import settings
from .models import init_pg
from .urls import setup_routes

"""
Run either of the following commands from the parent of current directory:

adev runserver producer --livereload

python3 -m producer.main
"""


def create_app():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    app = web.Application(middlewares=[
        web_middlewares.normalize_path_middleware(append_slash=True),
    ], client_max_size=2048**2)

    app.update(name='producer', settings=settings)

    # setup Jinja2 template renderer
    aiohttp_jinja2.setup(app, loader=jinja2.PackageLoader('producer', 'templates'))

    # create db connection on startup, shutdown on exit
    app.on_startup.append(init_pg)
    # app.on_cleanup.append(close_pg)

    # setup views and routes
    setup_routes(app)

    # setup middlewares
    # setup_middlewares(app)

    # setup aiojobs scheduler
    setup_aiojobs(app)

    # setup swagger documentation
    setup_swagger(app, swagger_url="api/doc")

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    web.run_app(app, host=app['settings'].HOST, port=app['settings'].PORT)
```

Comment: Why do you expect records in `/var/log/gunicorn/error_log` but write to access log?

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov Andrey, thank you for a response. Which logger should I use then? I tried `'aiohttp.access'`, `'aiohttp.server'` and `'aiohttp.web'`, but none of them writes neither to access_log, nor to error_log. What's the proper way to log just anything? If we come up with a working example, I'll gladly submit a pull-request with it to the logging documentation page, but so far I couldn't.